# How to use a modifed local version of a package?

Tags: julia

I installed the Mocha package like so:

```
julia> Pkg.add("Mocha")
```

Now I'd like to instead use a different Mocha package from a local clone of the repo where I've modified some of the files. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a symbolic link within your ~/.julia/v0.[versionNumber]/ directory

For example:

Mocha_clone  and Mocha_modified
ln -s Mocha_modified Mocha